# Get Request Uri in Identityserver login page

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, owin, openid, identityserver3

I am very new to Identityserver and owin. Here is my issue.
I have created an asp.net MVC application by using identityserver3 as my authentication service.
I want to access the request URI inside identity server login. I have customized the login page with MVC view (by using IdentityServer3.Samples).

This is the flow. Following URL need authentication to proceed. `https://www.myapp.com/customer/profile`
When somebody navigates to that URL it will automatically redirect to identity login page `https://www.myapp.com/identity/login?signin=2207991967207c8e306a8c08b3abd3b8`. After providing the correct user credentials it will redirect back to the request URL correctly, which is already handled by identityserver.

In my case, i have an another link inside the same identityserver login page, which should redirect to my own link with the request URL `https://www.myapp.com/customer/profile` as querystring parameter. How can I achieve this? Basically, i want to get the request URL inside login page.

Answer (score 1):

You have to override the handler for `AuthorizationCodeReceived` event on the client:

```
AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>{
    n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = /*your custom logic here*/;
}
```

The question seems to be a variation of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44449742/owin-openid-connect-external-login-doesnt-execute-specified-callback-url/) one

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to access the return url via

```
var env = Request.GetOwinContext().Environment;
var msg = env.GetSignInMessage(id); // id from querystring
var returnUrl = msg.ReturnUrl;
```

(taken from [login controller](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/blob/master/source/CustomLoginPage/CustomLoginPage/Controllers/LoginController.cs) in the example repo)

Comment: no it does not work there i am getting not what i expected. it is like `https://identity.codefox.com/identity/connect/authorize?client_id=app_central&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fcentral.codefox.com&response_mode=form_post&response_type=code%20id_token&scope=openid%20profile%20read%20write%20offline_access&state=OpenIdConnect.AuthenticationProperties%3DktxDeOqwyWvZhx1JKURF0e8yAMBpeU36_qMNj-Ib-hFNOF6HmN0rUPh3PjnRTQrHhy1KMd0Wr9eaOvKUoOEqAmBpqenO6G2GhtslpRGb7UTsYXiuaOkRCEUaqn5Be_EMYsWhVga00DUOE4Aki1pNVEdAwQpwhvKLs`

Comment: IdentityServer cannot nessecarily know what the user originally requested because that's several steps back in the OAuth flow.

Comment: Consider this example:
* Navigate to some url
* Client web application: Not authorized -> redirect to the identityserver authorization endpoint. The client app will remember the original URL but only it knows that.
* IdentityServer: Not authenticated -> redirect to signin
* (User Signs In)
* IdentityServer: Redirect back to authorization endpoint
* (User authorizes the client app)
* IdentityServer: Redirect back to client's oauth callback url.
* Client web application: Redirect the user back to the original url.

Comment: So basically, knowing what to do with the user once they're authorized is the responsibility of the client app, not the oauth provider (identityserver). The only thing that the client sends to the oauth provider are the scopes it wants access to (I.E. profile, etc.) and a "state" parameter. The client may then use that state parameter to know what the user was originally requesting, but that's private to the client app and probably just a random string.

Comment: thanks for your explation. sory i am new to this. Is there any other way to achieve this. At least in the client application.