# OWIN openid connect external login doesn't execute specified callback url

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, openid-connect, katana

I am using owin openid connect authentication where the authentication provider is hosted on a separate domain. The authentication process works nicely. I am able to view restricted pages upon successful login at the identity server.

But I want the external identity server to return back to "account/SignInCallback" controller action so that I can execute a few lines of code relevant for the member's account. In the browser's network activity it shows me "302 Found" for the "account/SignInCallback" but it doesn't hit the breakpoints attached to it. It directly goes to the request initiating url e.g. "account/Dashboard".

Is there an way I can force the system to return back to the specific url after login, even though requesting url was different?

```
public class AccountController : BaseController
{
    public AccountController() : base()
    {
    }

    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Dashboard()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult SignInCallback()
    {
        if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            // Read claims and execute member specific codes
        }
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public ActionResult Unauthorized()
    {
        return View();
    }
}
```

The startup class is below:

```
public sealed class Startup
{   
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        string ClientCallbackUri = @"https://client.local/account/SignInCallback";
        string IdServBaseUri = @"https://idm.website.com/core";
        string TokenEndpoint = @"https://idm.website.com/core/connect/token";
        string UserInfoEndpoint = @"https://idm.website.com/core/connect/userinfo";
        string ClientId = @"WebPortalDemo";
        string ClientSecret = @"aG90apW2+DbX1wVnwwLD+eu17g3vPRIg7p1OnzT14TE=";

        JwtSecurityTokenHandler.InboundClaimTypeMap = new Dictionary<string, string>();

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = "Cookies"
        });

        app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
        {
            ClientId = ClientId,
            Authority = IdServBaseUri,
            RedirectUri = ClientCallbackUri,
            PostLogoutRedirectUri = ClientUri,
            ResponseType = "code id_token token",
            Scope = "openid profile roles",
            TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
            {
                NameClaimType = "name",
                RoleClaimType = "role"
            },
            SignInAsAuthenticationType = "Cookies",

            Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
            {
                AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                {
                    // use the code to get the access and refresh token
                    var tokenClient = new TokenClient(
                        TokenEndpoint,
                        ClientId,
                        ClientSecret);

                    var tokenResponse = await tokenClient.RequestAuthorizationCodeAsync(n.Code, n.RedirectUri);

                    if (tokenResponse.IsError)
                    {
                        throw new Exception(tokenResponse.Error);
                    }

                    // use the access token to retrieve claims from userinfo
                    var userInfoClient = new UserInfoClient(UserInfoEndpoint);

                    var userInfoResponse = await userInfoClient.GetAsync(tokenResponse.AccessToken);

                    // create new identity
                    var id = new ClaimsIdentity(n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType);
                    //id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.GetClaimsIdentity().Claims);
                    id.AddClaims(userInfoResponse.Claims);

                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("access_token", tokenResponse.AccessToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("expires_at", DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(tokenResponse.ExpiresIn).ToLocalTime().ToString()));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("refresh_token", tokenResponse.RefreshToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("id_token", n.ProtocolMessage.IdToken));
                    id.AddClaim(new Claim("sid", n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst("sid").Value));

                    n.AuthenticationTicket = new AuthenticationTicket(
                        new ClaimsIdentity(id.Claims, n.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AuthenticationType, "name", "role"),
                        n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties);
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It looks all you need is to set

```
n.AuthenticationTicket.Properties.RedirectUri = n.RedirectUri;
```

in your `AuthorizationCodeReceived` delegate

Answer (score 0):

The individual auth templates do this by enabling AutomaticChallenge on the cookie middleware rather than the other auth middleware (OIDC in this case). Cookie redirects them to an AccountController login page, then they select  the auth method, do the auth redirects, return to the account controller for the additional steps you want to add, and then they finish by redirecting back to the original page.

Here's a later version of that template for ASP.NET Core:
https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/blob/rel/1.0.5/src/Rules/StarterWeb/IndividualAuth/Controllers/AccountController.cs
https://github.com/aspnet/Templates/blob/rel/1.0.5/src/Rules/StarterWeb/IndividualAuth/Startup.cs

Note much of this is managed by the Identity framework, but it's not required.