# How to redirect client app (instead of using initially requested url) after a successful login?

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4, openid-connect

I have an asp.net core application with OpenID Connect authentication all working properly. The thing is, I want to redirect the client after a successful login, instead of using the callback url that is embedded in the `state` property in the querystring. How do I do that from the `Client/Startup.cs`?

In the code example below, say the user bookmarked or type in `/home/Second`, and after a successful login, I want to always redirect to `/home/Index`.
How do I do this?

```cs
    [Authorize]
    public class HomeController : Controller 
    { 
         public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
         {
            return View(); 
         }

         public async Task<IActionResult> Second()
         {
            return View(); 
         }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need something like:

```cs
services.AddAuthentication().AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.Events = new OpenIdConnectEvents
                {
                    OnTicketReceived = ctx =>
                    {
                        // can be First, Second, Index, whatever
                        ctx.ReturnUri = "http://google.com"; 
                        return Task.CompletedTask;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: Thank you!, this works! Previously I was using OnTokenValidated but that didn't work.

Comment: It was my first [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46811961/1426685) on SO. Almost the same, but for owin. And as MS guys compet in changing the signatures each releace, today it looks different.